# how to upload unique message data on sever in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sqlite, android-volley

I am trying upload some message data to server from my android app.it uploaded the  server data well, But problem is, it is upload all message data every time when app started.**I want to upload only those message data which would not uploaded previously**.How to do this?

Here is my code of fetching and uploading the message data on server:

```
class SmsContent {


    public List<SmsInfo> getSmsInfo() {
        String[] projection = new String[] { "_id", "address", "person", "body", "date", "type" };
        ContentResolver cr = activity.getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, projection, "body"+" LIKE '%"+smsBuilder1+"%'or+" + "body"+" LIKE '%"+smsBuilder2+"%'", null, "date desc");
        assert cursor != null;


        int nameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex("person");

        smsbodyColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex("body");

        int i = 0;
        while (cursor.moveToNext() && i++ < 20) {
            SmsInfo smsInfo = new SmsInfo();
            smsInfo.setName(cursor.getString(nameColumn));
            smsInfo.setSmsbody(cursor.getString(smsbodyColumn).trim());


            per = (cursor.getString(smsbodyColumn));

            smsInfo.setName(null == personName ? smsInfo.getPhoneNumber() : personName);
            prepareListData(per);
            infos.add(smsInfo);

        }
        cursor.close();
        return infos;
    }

    private void prepareListData(final String per) {


        // Volley's json array request object
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + response);



                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
//                hidePDialog();

            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();

                params.put(VENDOR, "test");
                params.put(ORGMESSAGE, per);
                return params;
            }
        };
        // Adding request to request queue
        MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(stringRequest);
    }

  }
```

If anyone want to know more info please ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save recently received message date in `SharedPreferences` and have a condition in `query` so as to select the messages which are received after that date.

```
String dateFromSharedPreferences="2000-01-01"; 
try{ 
String dateFromSharedPreferences=getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
dateFromSharedPreferences=sharedPref.getString("LastMsgDate", "2000-01-01"); 
catch(Exception ex){}
Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri, projection, "(body"+" LIKE '%"+smsBuilder1+"%'or+" + "body"+" LIKE '%"+smsBuilder2+"%') and date>'"+dateFromSharedPreferences+"'", null, "date desc");
```

Dont forget to save the current last received sms date in the same `SharedPreferences`

```
    while (cursor.moveToNext() && i++ < 20) {
        if(i==1) saveDateToSharedPreferences(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("date")))
        //other codes here

    }
```

saveDateToSharedPreferences function will be as follows

```
    function saveDateToSharedPreferences(String LastMsgDate){
        SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
        editor.putString("LastMsgDate", LastMsgDate);
        editor.commit();
    }
```

Comment: There is some problem with 'date' in query and saveDateToSharedPreferences method.

Comment: tell me onething. why are u querying only 20 messages? u need the whole messages to upload right?

Comment: yes I need to upload all msg.. 20 just for demo.. which I have got from another source

Comment: I have tried according to ur suggestion .. But there is some error

Comment: Here is my complete code and log .Please see this.   http://pastebin.com/NAsiWS46

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129226/discussion-between-adi-and-jafarbtech).

Answer (score 1):

Make another `column` in your `table` and store data like whether it's **uploaded or not**. And upload the data which are not uploaded.

Comment: then how to identify and put condition at android side?

Comment: That is what I am saying maintain in android side not in server side.

Comment: I'm not creating any custom table.. Just dig message database.How to implement ur logic.please provide a sample If possible .

Comment: I doesn't know more about the message database, can you get the messages after some given specific time?

Comment: I'm getting message from phone and there is no specific time receive message as like other phones

Comment: The date field which you are getting is in which format check that and put a condition for that date field and maintain a SharedPreference for last sync mean API call and after that date fetch all the records.

Answer (score 1):

So, what you're dealing with here is local cache, mind you that this answer will give you the flow of a way to handle it, the coding is up to you, by the code you posted it seems your up to the task, here are your options:

1. `SharedPreferences`.
2. Android's built in sqlite.

`SharedPreferences` is an option, but - it would be more suitable for single variables, or for example, an object serialized into a `JSON` string.

In your case, creating and maintaining a local (on the phone itself, client-side) database would probably be better - since you're maintaining a messaging record, which is big and might reach numbers in the tens, you mentioned that you're not creating a custom table - you should, and since your code suggests that there IS a db somewhere in there, this is generally how I would go about this:

1. create a new table, holding all the known values plus 2 new columns (e.g. is_sent, is_received).
2. think of two situations: msg sent, vs. msg received - you might have sent it, the other side (server) might not get it.
3. Pull the msgs using the cursor (like you did), save them in an ArrayList, and their info in your new table, marking them all as false on the sent and received columns.
4. Send that list to your server (marking all of them as sent = true in the table).
5. make sure your server response returns a confirmation (either per id, or just a general "success:true"), and then in the onResponse callback - update your table (use you local list for id comparison if you need to, marking what is relevant with received = true).
6. modify the method that sends stuff on startup to pull the messages, and first compare them to your table,only send the msgs that are marked as sent=false && received=false, if in doubt - check the id, if it's not in your table - you don't know about it, so send it and make sure your server knows to compare msg id's cross-referenced with user id's to avoid duplicates.

All this requires both client side work and server side work, and possibly some help from your server-side/db guy, and again - this is a possible flow similar to chat message caching, and probably could be  greatly tweaked into efficiency when coding.

Hope this Helps.